# How can I add the float to the position on Y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The original code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FloatInAir : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float amplitude;          //Set in Inspector 
     public float speed;                  //Set in Inspector 
     private float tempVal;
     private Vector3 tempPos;

     void Start () 
     {
         tempVal = transform.position.y;
     }

     void Update () 
     {        
         tempPos.y = tempVal + amplitude * Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.time);
         transform.position = tempPos;
     }
}
```

But I want to keep the original position just changing the Y so I tried to change the transform.position line to :

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + tempPos, transform.position.z);
```

But doing plus is wrong.

Comment: what do u mean the plus is wrong?

Comment: you probably want to add `tempPos.Y` and not directly `tempPos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **transform.localPosition** instead of **transform.position**.

transform.localPosition will give the position of the transform relative to the parent transform.

Also You are assigning y position to `tempPos.y`so you should be adding `tempPos.y` and not `tempPos`.